# Spring boot execute maven repository

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I have an executable jar file. I can start it properly using command `java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar`.
I deployed it to internal maven repository and include it to spring boot app as an dependency. How can I execute that dependency as jar file? I want to create Schedule to execute it every day.

Comment: What about a batch to launch the jar every day ?

Comment: I'm not allowed to you jar file. I need to include it in maven repository and use.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Run the Spring-Boot Application and have it run the main method from the executable jar file? Run the jar individually - why do you include it in a Boot App then? Run the Boot App on a schedule and have it execute the jar?

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible option is unpack jar via maven plugin, update main class in spring-boot-maven-plugin and execute the command as mentioned below :

**Unpack the jar :**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.group</groupId>
                        <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
                        <version>0.0.1</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Update Main class**(add below tag in spring-boot-maven-plugin) in pom.xml : as you may be having multiple main classes in final jar.

```
<configuration><mainClass>any of the main class here</mainClass></configuration>
```

**Invoke the Main class**

```
java -cp final.jar -Dloader.main=<fullyqualifed_mainclass> org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

By this you can invoke any of the main class from final jar.